# Why I have these weird quota numbers in Firestore (App engine)?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Could somebody explain to me how possible is to have quota numbers like these:

Cloud Firestore Read Operations - 0.004794 Million Ops

Cloud Firestore Small Operations - 0.00004 Million Ops

Cloud Firestore API Calls - 8,802

Cloud Firestore Stored Data - 0.000213 GB

Data Sent to Cloud Firestore API - 0.000005 GB

Data Received from Cloud Firestore API - 0.000024 GB

**Cloud Firestore Entity Fetch Operations - 4,755.00 Million Ops**

Cloud Firestore Entity Write Operations - 0.000158 Million Ops

Cloud Firestore Entity Delete Operations - 0.000062 Million Ops

**Cloud Firestore Index Write Operations - 1,684.00 Million Ops**

**Cloud Firestore Query Operations - 39.00 Million Ops**

**Cloud Firestore Key Fetch Operations - 40.00 Million Ops**

Cloud Firestore Network Egress - 0.001388 GB

1. I know that I'm charged for reads/writes/storage etc, but I can't find any info about limits about Cloud Firestore Key Fetch Operations, Cloud Firestore Index Write Operations, Cloud Firestore Entity Fetch Operations. Should I be afraid of these values?
2. What is the difference between for example Cloud Firestore Read Operations and Cloud Firestore Entity Fetch Operations? They shouldn't be similar? (0.004794 Million Ops vs 4,755.00 Million Ops)
3. My app is under development stage and has only one user (me). DB has 25 indexes, some rules, and few hundreds of documents, nothing special. Google support is investigating for 9 days (and send me an email every two-three days because.. they are investigating). I contacted support because I think there wasn't any "Million ops" text next to for example "Cloud Firestore Entity Fetch" before (like here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage#google-cloud-platform-console). Can be translation_key bug?

I want to start my business next month and I'm afraid I don't understand enough the charges rules. What will happen if I run AdWords? Trillions of Operations? What Operations? **I started development today, and 5 minutes later I had Cloud Firestore Entity Fetch Operations - 19.00 Million Ops. Just only after login to my app and see the dashboard with 10 records in the table. Incredible :/**

I don't wanna be another 'How I lost 30k with firebase in one-day' guy :/. What do you think?

Comment: We're facing the same issue at the moment, 100 billion fetch ops. Just noticed the number today too, so no idea if its normal or crazy high.

Comment: @RonnelDavis but did you see much lower number, for example, a few days or week ago?

Comment: No, that's the issue. I do not have a baseline to compare it to, so unsure if it's normal or not.

Comment: The best way forward is  to contact the Firebase Support and open a ticket so we can take a further look into this issue. https://firebase.google.com/support

Comment: @Juancki, Thx for reply! I did it 10 days ago (via Google Cloud Support), and that's why I created here the question because my doubts blocked me to start with my business. ticket no: #23424144

Comment: I can see the case, the issue is related to a misrepresentation of the actual quotas. Your agent will provide a detailed explanation of the issue. For further questions I would ask you to put them in the case, as we can actuate faster.

Comment: "misrepresentation of the actual quotas"? Anyway, thank you @Juancki, can't wait for details!

Comment: I'll post the result of the investigation here once the engineering team finishes it. Have a nice day!

Comment: Im similarly struggling to understand how Firestore quotas work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009673/react-hooks-with-firestore-data-1-1k-reads-in-30-seconds-from-2-collections-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that in some quotas there was a change in the units shown in the Console. The unit in the client side from Ops to Million Ops.  But in the server side, we still use Ops instead of Million Ops.

There are only 450.00 entity fetch operations in total instead of 450.00 Million.